# How to get directories and and subdirectories count fastest way?

Tags: linux, find, disk-usage

I want to get the number of directories and sub directories.I tried following command which takes very long time . I tried waiting about an hour to finish the command.

#### commands I used

```
$ find . -type d | wc -l
```

and

```
$ du -ch | wc -l
```

Both commands took more than 1 hour and did not complete the main folder size I'm trying to get information is about 120 GB.

Comment: Is the filesystem in question a NFS mount or similar?

Comment: For reference, I just tried that `find` command on a directory structure containing 211G of data on a local disk and it took 0.952 seconds of CPU time.

Comment: How do you know it's 120GB if `du` never completed? Can you post the out of `df -Ti` on all the filesystems mounted at or bellow `.`?

Comment: The total size is pretty much irrelevant here, what matters is the number of files. If there are a lot of files, counting them will take a long time.

Comment: It is a NFS mount and shows using 'df -h'

Answer (score 3):

If you only want a single level, then there is a trick to doing this without having to enumerate the directory. If you want recursion, then what you've got is the best you're going to get.

The single level trick:

```
stat --printf='%h\n' /path/to/dir
```

...and subtract 2. The result is the number of directories within that directory (non recursive).

That command shows the number of hard links on the specified file. Whenever you create a directory inside a directory, the sub directory has a hard link entry to the parent directory, the `..`. So by creating a sub directory, you increase the number of hard links to the parent directory by one. But we subtract 2 because every directory starts off with 2 hardlinks. One hardlink is in the parent directory and points to it: the `dir` entry inside `/path/to`. The other hardlink is the directory containing a link to itself: the `.` entry.

---

However with recursion, you have to examine each directory. The problem is that there's no way to say "give me a list of only directories within this directory". You have to get a list of every single entry in the directory, and then `stat` each one to find out if it's a directory or a file.

Now when you stat the directory, you can use the above hardlink trick to find if that directory contains any sub directories, and thus you can save yourself a little bit of time and not descend into that directory. The `find` utility actually uses this trick to get a little performance gain in the process.

So basically, using `find` is going to be the best you can do if you want recursion.

Comment: Note that the hardlink trick doesn't work on all filesystems. It doesn't work on `btrfs` for instance. You can do `find . -type d -printf x -links 2 -prune | wc -c` to use it here.

Answer (score 2):

`find . -type d | wc -l` does not give you the correct value if there are newlines somewhere. Furthermore it counts the start directory which probably isn't intended. I do not believe that the pipeline is the bottleneck but this can easily be optimized:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -printf . | wc -c
```